# Weird (?) 3rd party lib issue with App Engine project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

Dunno if this is weird or if I´ve just missunderstood how Eclipse works for the past five years or so :-)

I have a Google App engine project, where I´ve put some 3rd party libs in my build path. Whenever I try to run my webapp however, I get a ClassNotFound-exception. I struggled with this for a while, until I eventually just copied my jars directly into the WEB-INF/lib direcory for the project in my workspace. Now everything works like a charm.

I´ve always been under the impression that Eclipse automatically puts my 3rd party libs in the WEB-INF/lib directory whenever I add them to my build path, but that does seem to be the case here. Could this be an issue with the Google App Engine plugin, or have I just missunderstood it all?

Can someone please clarify :-)

Comment: You misunderstood this, i'm afraid. Build path is for compiling your sources. When your app runs, however, the necessary libs need to be on the classpath. Otherwise, it's just going to throw that `CNFE`

Comment: You just missunderstood it all, eclipse doenn't put automagically classpath libraries in the WEB-INF/lib folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the App Engine plugin automatically puts your libs into WEB-INF/lib. It may do that for its own SDK libs, but not for 3rd party stuff. You have to put them there yourself in order for them to be uploaded.